# Was this kind of porcelain service common during some Chinese dynasty?

Tags: identification, medieval-china

Here is a Chinese porcelain service of particular (lotus ?) shape :

[image: Lotus flower shaped cups service ?]

The squared cup actually doesn't belong to the same set, but the fact that it fits perfectly makes me wonder : **was this kind of service usual during a particular dynasty, and did it have a main purpose (maybe a name) ?**

Here is the stamp on the cups, apparently the two first characters are related to the palace, although probably not to high-ranking people.  Update : apparently it reads "*Guan jiao nei zao*"/"*Guan yao nei zao*" ("Imperial Kiln for Inner Palace"), but the seal doesn't quite look like most of seals with this sentence : it has a different font and is sealed.

[image: Stamp on the cups]

Comment: What was the source of these photos? Is this your collection?

Comment: @Semaphore This item is presented in an auction in my city.  I am indeed considering if it might be of interest.

Comment: This is 官窯内造 written in [small seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script), but I don't think much of the penmanship.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou The reason I'm curious is because the 官窯内造 seal is commonly from around late Qing/early Republic period (~1900) but I haven't seen one written in such a style before. I do believe some Song era (~1000-1300) government workshops used the same phrase, but it seems they used yet another script. I'm quite curious this, do you have any more information on the auction item? Does the auctioneer perhaps have a web link? Be aware, btw, that there are a lot of 官窯内造 fakes today.

Comment: @Semaphore Indeed I couldn't find a similar looking seal online.  [Here](https://www.interencheres.com/meubles-objets-art/mobilier-objets-dart-tableaux-anciens-254627/lot-21078401.html) is a link to the piece on the auction website (in French), but there is not much information (I assume they don't have much expertise in Chinese antiques).